# Distance metric for vector of functions and real numbers

Tags: clustering, distance

I want to cluster points which have the following feature vector:

$$\theta = (f_1, f_2, \cdots, f_n, y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_m)$$

i.e. the first $n$ entries are functions $f_i$ ($\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$) and the last $m$ entries are real numbers $y_i$.

**Question:**

What would be a good distance metric for clustering?

Comment: A natural approach would be: $||\theta_1-\theta_2||_N\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\sum_{i=1}^n ||f_{1,i}-f_{2,i}||_\mathcal{F}^2 + \sum_{i=1}^m (y_{1,i}-y_{2,i})^2$ for some function norm $||.||_\mathcal{F}$. To determine which function norm is appropriate, we need to know a little bit more about your functions: do you observe them at discrete points? Or do you observe a program that you can execute at arbitrary input points?

Comment: @JohnMadden The functions can be calculated at arbitrary input points. The input range is also restricted to an interval $[x_{min}, x_{max}]$. What is your reasoning for using the squared $L^2$ distance, i.e. leaving our the square root $\sqrt{.}$?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Yes, they are really functions. I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @JohnMadden What I was also thinking of doing is scaling the features. For example, the $y_i$'s could be scaled to the range $[0,1]$ e.g. using `scikit-learn`'s `MinMaxScaler`. Although, I am not sure how one could scale the functions. Perhaps one could scale the function norm $||.||_\mathcal{F}$ such that it returns values in the range $[0,1]$?

Comment: This is how distance metrics must combine in order to have good properties like homogeneity and triange ineq (if you don't care about that do you). The restricted range helps a lot, and thank you for reporting that you can evaluate the function at arbitrary points. In this case, I would recommend starting with the $L_2$ distance between functions since it is "easy" to approximate: $||f_1-f_2||_{L_2}^2\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\int_{[x_{min},x_{max}]} (f_1(x)-f_2(x))^2 dx \approx \frac{1}{B} \sum_{b=1}^B (f_1(x_b)-f_2(x_b))^2$, where $x_b$ is either a random sample or a grid of points.

Comment: But you should try out other function norms too, like the $||f_1-f_2||_\infty\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=} \underset{x\in[x_{min},x_{max}]}{\max} |f_1(x)-f_2(x)|$. Since your functions are 1 dimensional, bisection or even just grid search should suffice for solving the optimization.

Comment: @JohnMadden Thanks! That was helpful.

Comment: happy to help, and oh yeah I forgot to address the scale issue you mentioned: I would divide the real numbers by the standard deviation of their column per usual, and for functions the analogous technique is probably something like to divide by $\sqrt{\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N ||f_{i,n}-\bar{f}_{i}||_2^2}$ where $f_{i,n}$ is the n'th observation of the i'th function type, and $\bar{f}_i$ is the pointwise mean of your observed function.